# How can I apply the style of a ToolBar CheckBox to a regular CheckBox?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, styles, toolbar

I would like to style a regular `CheckBox` so it looks like a `CheckBox` inside a `Toolbar`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <CheckBox Style="{What to put here?}">
    <Image Source="someImage.png" Stretch="None" />
  </CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Is there a way to obtain a reference to the `Style` use by the `ToolBar` and 'bind' to it?

**EDIT**: The reason for this is because I want a few simple buttons to control the `Visibility` of some elements and I don't want to use a `ToolBar` just for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.CheckBoxStyleKey}}">
    <Image Source="someImage.png" Stretch="None" />
  </CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to use a ToggleButton or make a control template, You might find the following urls useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.aspx
[WPF CheckBox with "Button" appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064658/wpf-checkbox-with-button-appearance)

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that I don't want to use a ToolBar control...