# How to restore default style for CheckBox on ToolBar?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, styles, toolbar

Problem is that ToolBar w/o any permission changes style of placed CheckBox (instead of tick box it looks like normal button). I want to restore original look of CheckBox with a minimum code.

This problem is opposite to the problem described here: [How can I apply the style of a ToolBar CheckBox to a regular CheckBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677156/in-wpf-how-can-i-apply-the-style-of-a-toolbar-checkbox-to-a-regular-checkbox)

Any help, please?

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for:

```
<CheckBox Style="{x:Null}" />
```

This should restore the default checkbox style.

Comment: Unfortanately, it does not restore the bullet in the checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

Well... it is not anarchy :o) this is the normal behavior from the toolbar. Maybe there is another way, but you can wrap your checkbox in a, let's say, Dockpanel to hide the style the Toolbar applies to the CheckBox.

Something like this would work:

```
<DockPanel>
    <CheckBox Content="Check 1"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Check 2"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I actually stumbled on the answer.  Try this:

```
<BulletDecorator
    Margin="0,5,0,0">
    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
        <CheckBox />
    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
        <TextBlock
            Width="100"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Foreground="Blue"
            Margin="5,0,0,0">
    Some text
    </TextBlock>
</BulletDecorator>
```

with, of course, modifications per your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, clicking "Some text" doesn't check the `CheckBox` like it would if you had a `<CheckBox content="Some Text"/>`.